# calculating value of cookie using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There are 2 Textboxes , user will input value and store in Java script variable after that i have to persist that value so storing that value in

> Blockquote

 cookies, again when user will input new value i want addition of that value with last value

Comment: please post your js script in jsfiddle

Comment: Do you need this to be done in Javascript? or Php ?

Comment: What do you have and what isn't working? http://www.php.net//manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: in my page i have button on button click a popup is coming (via ajax) in that popup there are 2 textboxes user will input values(perform some calculation with database values) and press ok button popup will be closed, again if click on button again popup will come and user will enter 2 values calculate this with database values and add this value to las result

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){  
$('.ok').click(function(){
var v_qty=$('.qty').val();
var v_hrs=$('.hrs').val();

var loadwatt=$('.loadwatt').val();
var total=0;
var check=0;
$.cookie('b_total');
check = $.cookie('b_total');
var count = parseInt($.cookie('b_total'));
 
 
 alert(count);
var total=(v_qty * loadwatt) * v_hrs;
total = parseInt(total) + count;
var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 1;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie("b_total", total, { expires: date });
 check = $.cookie('b_total');
 alert(check);
 


});
});

Comment: @Amitsingh no code in the comments! Edit the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you try to append the new value with your last value on the same cookie?

If i'm right first of all try to use this plugin to simplify the handling of cookies.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Then try this:

```
$("#yourInput").on("change", function()
{
    var actualVal = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    var yourCookie = $.cookie('yourCookie')
    if( yourCookie )
    {
        var newVal = parseInt(yourCookie, 10) + actualVal;
        $.cookie('yourCookie', newVal);
    }
    else
    {
        $.cookie('yourCookie', actualVal);
    }
});
```

Edit based in your code, try to parseInt with radix all the integer value. If you have float value, try parseFloat on that inputs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ok').click(function () {
        var v_qty = parseInt($('.qty').val(), 10);
        var v_hrs = parseInt($('.hrs').val(), 10);
        var loadwatt = parseInt($('.loadwatt').val(), 10);
        var total = 0;
        var check = 0;
        $.cookie('b_total');
        check = $.cookie('b_total');
        var count = parseInt($.cookie('b_total'), 10);
        alert(count);
        var total = (v_qty * loadwatt) * v_hrs;
        total = parseInt(total, 10) + count;
        var date = new Date();
        var minutes = 1;
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        $.cookie("b_total", total, {
            expires: date
        });
        check = $.cookie('b_total');
        alert(check);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply .... yes on button onclick event  i am trying  to append the new value with your last value on the same cookie when i am adding new value it not performing addition sometimes it's showing NAN or some times 120 230 like that but not adding. i am also using parseInt() function but it's showing NaN in alert.

Comment: Try to perform a parseInt(yourvalue, 10).
Here is a simple explication about the radix on the parseInt
http://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix

Comment: var count = parseInt($.cookie('b_total'));
 
 
 alert(count);
 
var total=(v_qty * loadwatt) * v_hrs;
total = parseInt(total) + count;

Comment: var count = parseInt($.cookie('b_total'), 10); alert(count); var total=(v_qty * loadwatt) * v_hrs; total = parseInt(total, 10) + count;

Comment: i have already tried this one still it's same error!!! that is NaN

Comment: I just edit my answer with your code, check it.